# Laravel 5 : Restrict access to controllers by User group

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5.1

I've started learning Laravel 5.1 and so far I'm liking it! But there is one thing I don't get yet..
In my previous project I had 2 specific controllers (eg: "normal", "extended") which , after a successfull login, were called based on the Users `user_group` from the database.

If "Foo.Bar" enters his valid credentials and has the group `normal` he is redirected to `NormalControler`. Since I wasn't using any framework I restricted access to the other group by setting a `$_SESSION` with the group and checking it. So if another group tried to access that controller he got redirected.

How would this be achievable in Laravel 5? So far I have a controller which is callable without an Authentication and one restricted by this code in `routes.php` :

```
// All routes in the group are protected, only authed user are allowed to access them
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {

    // TO-DO : Seperate Controller access
});
```

And the login looks like this :

```
public function performLogin()
    {   

        $logindata = array(
            'username' => Input::get('user_name'),
            'password' => Input::get('user_pass')
        );

        if( Auth::attempt( $logindata ) ){
            // return \Redirect::to( check group and access this controller based on it);
        }
        else {
           // TO-DO : Redirect back and show error message
           dd('Login failed!');
        }
    }
```

----- **EDIT** -----

I've run the artisan command and made this middleware as you suggested :

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Request;

class GroupPermissions
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $group)
    {
        // Check User Group Permissions
        if( $request->user()->group === $group ){
            // Continue the request
            return $next($request);
        }

        // Redirect
        return redirect('restricted');
    }
}
```

and edited this line into `Kernel.php` into `$routeMiddleware` :

```
'group.perm' => \App\Http\Middleware\GroupPermissions::class
```

I think this is done right so far, correct me if I'm wrong! Could I then do something like this to restrict the controllers?

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {

    Route::group( ['middleware' => 'group.perm', 'group' => 'normal'], function(){
        Route::get('/normal/index', 'DummyNormalController@index');
    });

    Route::group( ['middleware' => 'group.perm', 'group' => 'extended'], function(){
        Route::get('/extended/index', 'DummyExtendedController@index');
    });

});
```

Comment: Middleware should do that. I think

Comment: as others have said middleware will now do this - https://mattstauffer.co/blog/series/new-features-in-laravel-5.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here is what you might do. Once user is logged in, you would check his credentials, get his `user_group` and decide what controller he should be redirected to.

```
if( Auth::attempt( $logindata ) ){
    $user = Auth::user();

    if ($user->inGroup('normal')) {
         return redirect()->route('normal_controllers_named_route');
    }
    return redirect()->route('extended_controllers_named_route');
}

return redirect()->back()->withFlashMessage('don\'t get me wrong');
```

This will handle right routing after logging in.

The next portion where you need to protect you routes from unwanted user groups may be achieved with middlewares.

1. do an artisan command `php artisan make:middleware ShouldBeInGroup`
2. go to `app/http/Kernel.php` and add your new middleware to the `routeMiddleware` array. Key of the item might be anything you like. Let's call in `inGroup`. So: `'inGroup' => 'App\Http\Middleware\ShouldBeInGroup'`
3. Now, in your controller, in constructor, you are able to call this middleware

`$this->middleware('inGroup:extended');  //we also  passing the name of the group`

4. at lastly, work on the our middleware. Open newly created `ShouldBeInGroup` class and edit the handle method.

   ```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next, $groupName)
   {
       if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->inGroup($groupName)) {
            return $next($request);
       }

       return redirect('/');
   }
   ```
5. And finally you should work on `inGroup` method, that should return `true` of `false`. I assume that you have `user_group` field your users table. Then in your `User` eloquent model add the method

   ```
   public function inGroup($groupName) {
       return $this->user_group == $groupName;
   }
   ```

---

### Edit

if you want to use this middleware in your routes, you can do the following

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::get('/normal/index', ['middleware' => 'group.perm:normal', 'uses' =>'DummyNormalController@index']);
}
```

But generally it's better to put all your middlewares into your Controller's constructor

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('group.perm:normal'); // you can also pass in second argument to limit the methods this middleware is applied to : ['only' => ['store', 'update']];
}
```

---

And also on this note, Laravel provides built in `auth` middleware that you can use

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('group.perm:normal');
}
```

so then your routes would become much cleaner, just:

```
Route::get('normal/index', 'DummyNormalController@index');
```

Comment: Could you look into my Edit? Was this basically done right as I've understood it?

Comment: @AndrewMalinnkov Thank you, now it's way more understandable to me! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do that is using middlewares. [See the doc here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware)

You can easily create a middleware using the following artisan command:

```
php artisan make:middleware ExtendedMiddleware
```

If you can't or don't want to use artisan, you need to create a class in The `App/Http/Middleware` folder.

In this class you'll need the following method to handle the request. In the method you can check for the user group.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // check user group
    if( user_group_ok )
        return $next($request); // Continue the request

    return redirect('restricted'); // Redidrect 
}
```

You can then use this middleware in your `route.php` file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{

    // Logged-in user with the extended group
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'extended'], function()
    {
        // Restricted routes here
    });

    // Normal routes here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Middleware called : PermissionFilter

In PermissionFilter, you check if requesting user is in the group or not.

I can't provide a demo for now, but if you want I can make a demo later.

L5 middleware: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware